# Mongodb read query very slow with Spring Data and fast with Morphia

Tags: java, mongodb, spring-data, spring-data-mongodb, morphia

I would like to convert my project from Morphia to Spring Data but some basics query are very slow with Spring Data.

For example:

```
@Override
public List<PTDefaultBlacklistContact> findByBlacklistId(ObjectId defaultBlacklistId, int limit, int offset, String sortBy) {
    Query query = Query.query(Criteria.where("blacklistId").is(defaultBlacklistId));

    if (limit != 0)
        query.limit(limit);

    if (offset != 0)
        query.skip(offset);

    if (StringUtils.hasLength(sortBy))
        query.with(new Sort(sortBy));


    log.debug("findByBlacklistId query={}", query);
    return mongoOperations.find(query, PTDefaultBlacklistContact.class);
}
```

takes ~2 minutes

And with Morphia

```
@Override
public List<PTDefaultBlacklistContact> findByBlacklistId(ObjectId defaultBlacklistId, int limit, int offset, String sortBy) {
    Query<PTDefaultBlacklistContact> q = createQuery().disableValidation().filter("blacklistId", defaultBlacklistId).limit(limit)
        .offset(offset);
    if (StringUtils.hasLength(sortBy)) {
        q.order(sortBy);
    }
    return q.asList();
}
```

It takes ~5 seconds.

My configuration is basic so it is quiet weird to understand.
I juste have this in my application.yml and there is the spring boot mongodb auto configuration.

```
spring.data.mongodb.uri: mongodb://serv1,serv2,serv3/${mongodb.database}
```

Any idea ?
I am wondering if the cause could be the events of the lifecycle.

Thank you

**edit:**

Models:

PTDefaultBlacklistContact

```
@Document(collection = "PTDefaultBlacklistContact")
public class PTDefaultBlacklistContact extends PTModel {
private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;
@Deprecated
@DBRef
protected PTDefaultBlacklist blacklist;
private   String             identifier;
@Indexed
private   ObjectId           blacklistId;

private List<PTHistory> history;

public PTDefaultBlacklistContact() {
}

@Override
public int hashCode() {
    int prime = 31;
    int result = 1;
    result = prime * result + ((blacklistId == null) ? 0 : blacklistId.hashCode());
    result = prime * result + ((identifier == null) ? 0 : identifier.hashCode());
    return result;
}

@Override
public boolean equals(Object obj) {
    if (this == obj) {
        return true;
    }
    if (getClass() != obj.getClass()) {
        return false;
    }
    PTDefaultBlacklistContact other = (PTDefaultBlacklistContact) obj;
    if (blacklistId == null) {
        if (other.blacklistId != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!blacklistId.equals(other.blacklistId)) {
        return false;
    }
    if (identifier == null) {
        if (other.identifier != null) {
            return false;
        }
    } else if (!identifier.equals(other.identifier)) {
        return false;
    }
    return true;
}

@Override
public String toString() {
    return "PTDefaultBlacklistContact{" +
        "identifier='" + identifier + '\'' +
        ", blacklistId=" + blacklistId +
        '}';
}

public List<PTHistory> getHistory() {
    return history;
}

public void setHistory(List<PTHistory> history) {
    this.history = history;
}

public String getIdentifier() {
    return identifier;
}

public void setIdentifier(String identifier) {
    this.identifier = identifier;
}

@Deprecated
public PTDefaultBlacklist getBlacklist() {
    return blacklist;
}

@Deprecated
public void setBlacklist(PTDefaultBlacklist blacklist) {
    this.blacklist = blacklist;
}

public ObjectId getBlacklistId() {
    if (blacklist != null) {
        blacklistId = blacklist.getId();
    }
    return blacklistId;
}

public void setBlacklistId(ObjectId blacklistId) {
    this.blacklistId = blacklistId;
}

}
```

PTHistory

```
public class PTHistory {

private Long       date;
@DBRef
private PTCampaign campaign;

public Long getDate() {
    return date;
}

public void setDate(Long date) {
    this.date = date;
}

public PTCampaign getCampaign() {
    return campaign;
}

public void setCampaign(PTCampaign campaign) {
    this.campaign = campaign;
}


}
```

Comment: That is very odd.  Are there any other code differences?  What does the `PTDefaultBlacklistContact` class look like?  Any `@DBRef` annotations?

Comment: Are you actually running this against the same datasource or two different ones? I ask because the timing difference screams out "indexes", where one source has the field indexed and the other does not.

Comment: Hi, thanks for the comments. I have edited the first post with some classes. And @BlakesSeven this is the same datasource, just a different library : morphia vs spring data.

Comment: Any chance of a comlete "minimal" example to replicate, being "both" implementations, being the spring-mongo one and the morphia one. I do note that as commented earlier you are indeed using `@DBRef`, so I would suspect that there is an automatic "expansion" of the linked reference happening in the slower example that does not automatically happen in the other. DBRef's are really quite "evil", and as such it's generally better to use alternate means of referencing data from other collections.

Comment: Thanks @BlakesSeven. I have tried some samples with and without references and it is a lot better without ! I am going to work on it and try to replace references by a classic ID of another objects.

Comment: Looks like you just got an answer from the person who would actually know best. As noted you can indeed turn of the eager resolve ( which is causing overhead by additional queries ) and just do a lazy load just like they would be handled in morphia. But as mentioned, there are other issues with `DBref` that can cause other problems, so if you can handle your references another way then it's probably a good idea.

Answer (score 5):

With your DBRef configuration above, you'll get all of them resolved eagerly by default with Spring Data. That will result in additional queries issued for every DBRef encountered when reading a document.

We usually recommend using `@DBRef(lazy = true)` to avoid those calls and rather only read them once they get accessed.

Comment: Thank you Oliver. I have added some details. Do you know why it is fast with Morphia (with references and lazy = false) and so slow with Spring Data ? (same configuration, with references and lazy = false)

Comment: Same in my case, Accessing documents with Spring Data is relative slow.
@BkSouX did you find any workaround or better solution?

Comment: Spring Data can be very slow if you have a lot of @DbRef. It require a lot of db request to load all referenced data. You may have to break the link between two collections to improve performance

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Blakes Seven, here is my investigation with some tests for the same collection. I just added or removed references.

**With Morphia with references:**

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1472k    0 1472k    0     0  1970k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 1968k

real    **0m0.752s**
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.000s

**With Morphia without references:**

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1472k    0 1472k    0     0  3022k      0 --:--:-- --:--:-- --:--:-- 3016k

real    **0m0.492s**
user    0m0.012s
sys     0m0.000s

**With Spring Data with references:**

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1472k    0 1472k    0     0  96901      0 --:--:--  0:00:15 --:--:--  338k

real    **0m15.567s**
user    0m0.008s
sys 0m0.004s

**With Spring Data with LAZY references:**

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1472k    0 1472k    0     0   703k      0 --:--:--  0:00:02 --:--:--  703k

real    **0m2.111s**
user    0m0.016s
sys 0m0.000s

**With Spring Data without references:**

% Total    % Received % Xferd  Average Speed   Time    Time     Time  Current
                                 Dload  Upload   Total   Spent    Left  Speed
100 1472k    0 1472k    0     0   887k      0 --:--:--  0:00:01 --:--:--  887k

real    **0m1.722s**
user    0m0.008s
sys     0m0.012s

I really don't understand why this is so fast with Morphia without using lazy references. Or so slow with Spring Data with references. Someone have an idea ?